# Not able to find files at location "/sys/class/net/" in android 7.1.2

Tags: java, android, filesystems

Below code work in 4.1.1 version returning all file names, but the same code is not working in 7.1.2, is there any specific reason? Please help me.. Thanks in advance

```
String[] list = new File("/sys/class/net/").list();

    if(null != list){
    for(String s : list){
         Log.e("KOI", ""+s);
    }
    }else{
         Log.e("KOI", "NO LIst");
    }
```

Comment: Also same code working in android 6.1 version

Comment: Try  new File("/").list(); and you will get nothing too. Times have changed.

Comment: Thannks for reply @greenapps, new File("/").list(); I tried I am getting list of below files                                  
02-04 14:16:07.369: E/KOI(23494): sepolicy
02-04 14:16:07.369: E/KOI(23494): service_contexts
02-04 14:16:07.369: E/KOI(23494): storage
02-04 14:16:07.369: E/KOI(23494): sys
02-04 14:16:07.369: E/KOI(23494): system
02-04 14:16:07.370: E/KOI(23494): ueventd.qcom.rc

Comment: Very strange files. Strange names starting with a date. Very special.

Comment: Files names are sepolicy, service_context, storage, sys, system, etc. Their are more few files..

Comment: Strange. At Android 7+ it should give null. And what does `.listFiles()` deliver?

Comment: It is also giving same null...

Comment: Yes that should give null. Normal in Android 7+. But why are you now suddenly saying 'same null'? You were telling that you got file names before.

Comment: If I try for new File("/").list(); it return file names including 'sys', but if I try new File("/sys/class/net/").list(); it return me null.. is there any specific reason for version 7.0+

Comment: `If I try for new File("/").list(); it return file names including 'sys',` Well than i would like to know what `new File("/").listFIles();`delivers of course. Compare '.list()` with `.listFiles()`.

Comment: I tried File("/sys/class/net/").listFiles(); and it also return null. I won't tried for File("/").listFiles(); might be it will return file objects but when we try to navigate sys/class or sys/class/net it return null.. Till Android version 6.0 I check both location using file manager And I am able to see those files but the same thing I tried in 7.0+ only I am able to see sys folder.